# How to remove line richTextBox when Keys.Enter

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have to richTextBox.
When I Keys.Enter in richTextBox2 , Text send to rich text.
I use this code for  richtextbox2 , but still leaving an empty line (whitespace).

[image]

```
private void richTextBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
  {
    richTextBox1.Text += "Plan1" + ":   " + richTextBox2.Text + '\n';
    richTextBox2.Text = "";
    richTextBox2.SelectionStart = 0;
  }
}
```

How do I delete all lines when keys.Enter?

Comment: try editing your question to add an example of the text input in each textbox and the desired text when you press Enter

Comment: Get rid of the "+" on your line of code: `richTextBox1.Text += "Plan1"...`

Answer (score 3):

> *I use this code for richtextbox2 , but still leaving an empty line (whitespace)*

If I understand you correctly, you want to completely clear `richTextBox2` when the user presses `Enter` (and you want to move the text to `richTextBox1`), but after your code executes, there is a blank line in `richTextBox2` and the cursor is set on the second line.

If that's correct, then the problem is that the `Enter` key is still being processed, so we need to also hook into the `KeyPress` event to intercept the keystroke and set the selection start.

In order to do this, we need some way for the `KeyDown` event to let the `KeyPress` event know that it should throw away the keystroke. We can do this with a `bool` field that we set to `true` in the  `KeyDown` event, and then check it (and set it back to `false`) in the `KeyPress` event.

For example:

```
// Flag variable that allows KeyDown to communicate with KeyPress
private bool cancelKeyPress = false;

private void richTextBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += $"Plan1:   {richTextBox2.Text}\n";
        richTextBox2.Text = "";

        // Set our flag so KeyPress knows we should ignore this key stroke
        cancelKeyPress = true;
    }
}

private void richTextBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (cancelKeyPress)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        richTextBox2.SelectionStart = 0;

        // Set our flag back to false again
        cancelKeyPress = false;
    }
}
```

---

Note: According to the image you recently added, it also appears that you want `richTextBox1` to *only* contain what was in `richTextBox2` when the `Enter` key was pressed.

If this is the case, then we can simply replace the `+=` operator (which adds the string to the existing `Text`), with the `=` operator (which does a direct assignment):

```
richTextBox1.Text = $"Plan1:   {richTextBox2.Text}\n";
```

Comment: tnx for complete Response
but I don't khow why my problem was not resolved